# LINQ generic function for find in a enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a method that with a generic enumerable of type T it finds inside it using in the where the term i specify

```
public static object findInList<T>(T[] list, string searchTerm, string seachIndex)
{
    string normalized1 = Regex.Replace(seachIndex, @"\s", "");
    var sel = (from l in list
                     where normalized1.Equals([the item i want to compare])
                     select l).FirstOrDefault();
    return sel ;
}
```

i need this because i want to create a generic method for search an item in my array that i can customize in some way (below the code in its original way)

```
[...]
string normalized1 = Regex.Replace(seachIndex, @"\s", "");
sel = (from l in list
        where normalized1.Equals(l.Ordine)
        select l).FirstOrDefault();
[...]
```

[edit]
Thanks to Servy for the answer. For full index of this answer i add here how to call this method

```
Func<XXX, string> keySelector = delegate(XXX b) { return b.XX; };
var return = findInList<XXX>(list, keySelector, seachIndex);
```

Where XXX is the type of the list and XX is the property you want to compare for the search

Comment: How about adding a 4th parameter where you pass in a delegate?

Comment: I don't understand what u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is for your method to accept a selector, some function that determines what you should compare for each of your objects.

```
public static T findInList<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    Func<T, string> keySelector,
    string searchTerm,
    string seachIndex)
{
    string normalized1 = Regex.Replace(seachIndex, @"\s", "");
    return (from l in sequence
            where normalized1.Equals(keySelector(l))
            select l).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can also return a `T` instead of an `object`, since you know that that's what it is, ensuring that the caller doesn't need to cast it back to what it is.  You can accept an `IEnumerable` instead of an array since you're only ever iterating it, thus giving the caller more flexibility while still letting you do everything that you need to do.

Comment: How can i call this method with the Func<>? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Pass in a method accepting an object of the type in the sequence and returning a string.  You can use a lambda if you want, although you don't have to.  You can look up the documentation for lambda for plenty of examples.

Comment: @Servy It looks like the OP wants to do a search and replace. In that case you need to use `Expression<Func<T, string>>` then convert that to a `PropertyInfo` so that you can get both the `get` and `set` of the property, then call `get` `replace` then `set`.

Comment: @Aron He's only using replace to remove spaces from his search text.  It appears he's simply looking for the first item that matches that search text.